# What do these numbers mean on a transformer schematic?

Tags: transformer, schematics

What does the `.7`, `.6`, `1`, `.5`, `.6`, `1.2`, and `.3` mean in this picture? Why isn't there a number between terminal 8 and 6?

[image: transformer]

Comment: Turns/V??   Is 6  a centre tap of 8,12 ??

Comment: I might guess that the numbers on the transformer windings show the turns ratio between windings. Some info on voltages might confirm this guess.  The bobbin or frame that the transformer is built on may have space for 18 (or more) terminals or pins, but not all are used.

Comment: Maybe you should post a bigger picture with more schematics, so people can determine if this is a high-frequency circuit, or a plain AC.

Comment: It's from a switching power supply for a 1980's IBM CRT monitor, if that narrows it any.